# P4 merge error, No target file(s) in both client and branch view

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

First of all, I have a stream root named "//streams/main".
Then, I created a sub stream named "//streams/branchA" whose parent is "//streams/main". and I always worked on my own stream - branch A

Now, I want to do a down integration, from main to branch A. On my dev machine, I have synced my local client to latest version of branch A. Then, I input the following command (the command was generated by the dialog of P4, Merge/Integrate, I copied it out from log window of P4)

```
p4 merge -c 101005 -r -S //streams/BranchA -s //streams/BranchA/...@label_20130901
```

but, I got the error

```
Integration errors: No target file(s) in both client and branch view.

There are a total of 1 errors.
```

I don't know where I made a mistake, and how to fix it?

My dev machine is WIN8, P4 win client version is 2013 March 20.

Answer (score 11):

In my particular case, the following was the problem:

Using Perforce client (version: 2014 January 15) I was attempting to refresh a stream, from a parent stream.

When In the **depot view**, using Merge/integrate a fitler was added automatically on the filter tab, this was set to source filter, but the filer paths were that of the target, hence all files were filterd out.

Solutions are:

- Remove the filter paths from the filter tab
- Set the filter to target filter (asuming the paths are that of the target)

NB - This particular UI release *appears* to be somewhat unstable, as it has multiple problems, many to do with refreshing the UI or refreshing it's state and displaying correct menu options.

Comment: Removing the filter paths in the filter tab fixed this issue for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well you might want to look at this:
[Add new folder to depot in P4V client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226056/create-new-branch-in-p4v-client)

Also I've found that if I do not have the parent folder in my view, it doesn't want to do the integration. For instance lets say that `//streams` is excluded as tree, but the subtree `//streams/main` is included - then you'll not be able to integrate it into new branch below `//streams` (you will not be able to integrate into `//streams/branchA`).

Comment: An empty workspace mapping is mapped to nothing 
just as a workspace mapping with a global negation (and nothing else) maps nothing.

So I would have to ask why your workspace mapping isn't simply the line of what you want to include, with no + or -'s.  I could see perforce getting confused by this approach.